# Haskell - parse error in input

Tags: haskell

I have the following code that returns all numbers in the input list within the range
given by the first two arguments:

```
inRange :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
inRange a b xs = [if (x > a && x < b) then x | x <- xs]
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
parse error on input '|'
```

Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question but I really don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `if … then … else …`. I'm currently not really capable of providing a well written answer, so here's the short one: `[x | x <- xs, x > a, x < b]`. Feel free to use it in an answer.

Comment: I noticed that you had two questions in a row that had to do with incorrect syntax.  What resources are you using to learn Haskell?  Maybe I could point you at some more to help you learn the syntax better.  SO isn't really the place to go when you have syntax problems (a parse error always means it's syntax), those kinds of questions tend to clutter up the site.  I'd like to help you learn the syntax, but I don't think SO is the place to be learning it.  Let me know what you're currently referencing and I'll try to add several more that should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an `else` to that if statement. All `if`s in haskell have an `else` too.
The reason that an error about `|` comes up is that the parser is expecting an `else`, and it found a `|`.

So either you want

```
[if (x > a && x < b) then x else ??? | x <- xs]
```

or you want

```
[x | x <- xs, x > a, x < b]
```

Which can in turn be rewritten as

```
filter (\x -> x > a && x < b) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is one of the more common ways of using list comprehension.

List comprehension is described in [Haskell98 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.11) as having this

```
aexp    ->  [ exp | qual1 , ... , qualn ]   (list comprehension, n>=1)
qual    ->  pat <- exp  (generator)
|   let decls   (local declaration)
|   exp (guard)
```

what is means is that you provide between `[` and `|` what you are trying to have as a  new list element. This is where you use functions to change your list elements such as `[ head a |` will make a list of heads of some `a`

After `|` come qualifiers.
They can be

- generators (like `x <- xs` )
- local declarations
- or guards

What you need in your case are 2 guards (`x > a` and `x < b`) and one generator (`x <- xs`)
so what you need is

`[ x | x <- xs , x > a, x < b ]`

Some argue that list comprehension is for begginers and should later be substituted with higher order functions like `filter` and `map` so in your case you would acutally only need `filter`

some examples

```
inRange' a b xs = filter (\ x -> (x > a) && (x < b) ) xs
-- eta reduced version (without using xs)
inRange'' a b = filter (\ x -> (x > a) && (x < b) )
```